# Java - How to use the format specifier string "%6d | %5d | %6.2f%n

Tags: java

I want to use the format specifier string  "%6d | %5d | %6.2f%n" to format a table in Java, the ways I have tried has given me errors, I would like to use it in the piece of code below using `System.out.printf();`

```
 System.out.printf(" Person |  Mark   |Difference from mean ");
 for (int index4 = 0; index4 < numberOfMarks; index4++) 
     System.out.println((index4 + 1) + "|" +  marksArray[index4] + "|" + 
                       (meanMark - marksArray[index4]));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Post the complete code and the error  you get.

Comment: Thanks Rikayan that helped!

Answer (score 3):

You've mixed up [println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)) and [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

- `println` takes a `String` and writes it to the screen, followed by a newline character. This is the method you should use to print the heading, `" Person ... mean "`.
- `printf` takes a format string like `"%6d | %5d | %6.2f%n"` followed by the arguments to substitute, as separate arguments. Calls to `printf` look like

  ```
  System.out.printf("%6d | %5d | %6.2f%n", 0, 42, -12);
  ```

  The arguments in a method call are always separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String's static method [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

```
System.out.println(String.format("...", args))
```